# Configure local DNS from Java (for AWS lambda)

Tags: java, dns, aws-lambda

So I'm creating a AWS lambda application and it would be really helpful if I could create a local dns bindings(something that functions like `/etc/hosts`) in Java. Is that possible? If so, please provide some code examples, thanks!

Comment: Are you placing the function inside a VPC?

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I will be running it on aws lambda

Comment: @random you didn't answer my question at all. Are you placing the Lambda function inside a VPC?

Comment: @MarkB no I am not

Comment: Then as far as I know you can't do what you are asking.